# problems with null and empty string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, arraylist, null

```
class ToDoList { 
    public static void toDO() {

        List<string[]> addEntry = [];
        bool toDoLoop = true;

        while (toDoLoop) {
            Clear(); 
            WriteLine("\n\t\tHere is your to do list!");

            for (int i = 1; i < addEntry.Count; i++)
            {
                WriteLine($"\n\t\tTo Do {i}: {addEntry[i][0]}");
            }
            Write("\n\t\t[N]ew Entry\t[E]xit\t");

            string? userChoice = ReadLine();
            switch (userChoice)
            {
                case "n":
                case "N":
                    Write("\n\t\tAdd New Entry: ");
                    string?[] newToDo = new string[1];

                    newToDo[0] = ReadLine();

                    if (newToDo.Length == 0) { 
                        WriteLine("\n\t\tEntries can't be null!"); 
                    }

                    else { 
                        addEntry.Add(newToDo); 
                    }
                    break;

                case "e":
                case "E":
                    Clear();
                    WriteLine("\n\n\t\tClosing To Do!");
                    toDoLoop = false;
                    break;

                default:
                    Clear();
                    WriteLine("\n\t\tInvalid Entry!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a different variants with having the add entry inside both the if and the else, but i don't get it to work. Am i thinking completely wrong or am i at least on the right path?

```
if (newToDo[0] == "")

if (newToDo[0] != )

if (newToDo[0] is null)

if (newToDo[0] is not null)

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newToDo[0]))
```

Comment: Since you are apparently dealing with "entries" and "Todos" create classes that model an "Entry" and a "Todo". That should result in code much easier to read than using multiple levels of nested collections.

Comment: What is even the question here?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays always have a **fixed length**. Anything that changes this is actually a *new array*. So when you have this line:

```
string?[] newToDo = new string[1];
```

we can know that `newToDo.Length` will **always** be `1`, whether or not you've ever set a value for any of the items, unless you assign a whole new array to the reference. And therefore this check:

```
if (newToDo.Length == 0) {
```

will **never** be `true`. We already know we set it to an array with a `.Length` property of `1`.

So which of the alternatives should you use? In my experience, the last option is most correct:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newToDo[0]))
```

but sometimes this is also useful:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newToDo[0]))
```

---

But one wonders why you have a list of `string[]` at all, instead of a list of `string` (no array), which would be much simpler and still seems to meet your needs here.

---

While I'm here, indexer (`[]`) properties in C# start at **`0`**, not `1`, so this code is suspect:

```
for (int i = 1; i < addEntry.Count; i++)
```

You may want something more like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < addEntry.Count; i++)
{
    WriteLine($"\n\t\tTo Do {i++}: {addEntry[i][0]}");
}
```

And then also make a corresponding `-1` adjustment when reading an input of which line number to use.